# SQL fetch with user supplied array

Tags: php, sql, fetch

I'm trying to build a search function using tags,

My data structure in MySQL

```
parts                           parts_to_tags            tags
---------------------- ----    -------------------      -----------------
| part_id | part_name     |    |id|part_id|tag_id|      |tag_id|tag_name|
|  1      | 20lb Sledge   |    | 1|      1|     1|      |     1|Hammer  |
|  2      | Framing Hammer|    | 2|      1|     2|      |     2|Sledge  |
|         |               |    | 3|      2|     1|
```

I have a list of tags supplied by the user in an array, and I want to compare it to these tables to return all the results, so if the user asks for hammers both tools should be returned, though if they ask for both or just sledge only the 20lb sledge should be returned. I don't want to use the SQL "IN" because I want to use this as a drill down, not if any tag exists but all tags must exist for a result.

My code:

```
    $keywords = $_POST['tags'];
     // Returns: Array ( [0] => Sledge [1] => Hammer )

    $getInventory = $conn -> prepare("SELECT * FROM 
            parts
            LEFT JOIN parts_to_tags ON parts.part_id = parts_to_tags.part_id
            LEFT JOIN tags ON parts_to_tags.tag_id   = tags.tag_id
            ");

    $getInventory -> execute();

    $partArray = $getInventory -> fetchAll();


             $matched = !array_diff($keywords, $partArray);

             print_r($matched);
```

However, $partArray seems to be a deep array, so I cannot use array_diff. Does anyone have a different way to go about this? I've tried using a couple different fetch types to but I keep getting array to string conversion errors on the array_diff.

Thanks

Comment: please foreach () Try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a `WHERE` clause in the query; it will return the entire table and this is not what you need. More, even if you add a `WHERE` clause, `LEFT JOIN` will still return more rows that you need.

A possible solution to your problem could be:

```
SELECT p.part_id, p.part_name, GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag_name ORDER BY t.tag_name SEPARATOR '|') AS tags
FROM parts p
    INNER JOIN parts_to_tags pt ON p.part_id = pt.part_id
    INNER JOIN tags t ON pt.tag_id = t.tag_id
WHERE t.tag_name IN ('Hammer', 'Sledge')
GROUP BY p.part_id
```

It selects the parts that have at least one of the tags and also the list of tags associated with each part, sorted ascending and separated by '|'.

Of course, the list of tag names in the `IN ()` condition will be generated in the PHP code from `$keywords`.

The `PHP` code after you run the query:

```
// Sort the keywords ascending
sort($keywords);
// Concatenate them, use '|' as separator
$allTags = implode('|', $keywords);
// Get the result set
$parts = array();
foreach ($getInventory -> fetchAll() as $row) {
    // Keep only the parts that have all the tags
    if ($row['tags'] == $allTags) {
        $parts[] = $row;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** a simplified version of the query that returns only the parts that have all the specified tags (no extra PHP processing is needed):

```
SELECT p.part_id, p.part_name, COUNT(t.tag_name) AS nbTags
FROM parts p
    INNER JOIN parts_to_tags pt ON p.part_id = pt.part_id
    INNER JOIN tags t ON pt.tag_id = t.tag_id
WHERE t.tag_name IN ('Hammer', 'Sledge')       # <----------------+
GROUP BY p.part_id        #                                       |
HAVING nbTags = 2         # The number of strings in this list ---+
```

Comment: I had tried using the where clause and the group by but wasn't getting the results I wanted, this seeems to be getting me a lot closer, I just need to figure out now how to use multiple tags and still have results. Right now the if statement fails if I use 2+ tags.

Comment: By default, the comparison of string columns in MySQL is [**not** case sensitive](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html). The comparison in PHP **is** case sensitive. Maybe this is the cause it doesn't work for you. You have two options: either make the keywords lowercase (`$keywords = array_map('strtolower', $keywords);` before using them or move the comparison to MySQL entirely. For the second option you have to add `HAVING tags = 'Hammer|Sledge'` at the end of the query and it should return only the parts that has all the tags.

Comment: I updated the answer, added a better query does doesn't require any PHP post-processing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can resolve as follows. Multidimensional array diff

```
function arrayRecursiveDiff($aArray1, $aArray2) {
  $aReturn = array();

  foreach ($aArray1 as $mKey => $mValue) {
    if (array_key_exists($mKey, $aArray2)) {
      if (is_array($mValue)) {
        $aRecursiveDiff = arrayRecursiveDiff($mValue, $aArray2[$mKey]);
        if (count($aRecursiveDiff)) { $aReturn[$mKey] = $aRecursiveDiff; }
      } else {
        if ($mValue != $aArray2[$mKey]) {
          $aReturn[$mKey] = $mValue;
        }
      }
    } else {
      $aReturn[$mKey] = $mValue;
    }
  }
  return $aReturn;
} 

  $arr1 =    arrayRecursiveDiff($big_array,$small_array);
```